# Why my IP address received is reversed? Given - 12.0.0.100, received as 100.0.0.12 in C

Tags: c, ip, ip-address, endianness, radius

I am testing RADIUS-DISCONNECT options.

Server sends disconnect request to disconnect (Cmd: `cat packet.txt | radclient -c 10 -i 40 -x 12.0.0.1:3799 disconnect "Secret"`)

My RAIDUS server is configured as 12.0.0.100. RADIUS client IP is configured as 12.0.0.1.

Sending packets from server captured the same using packet capture command. Packet capture says source IP as: Source: 12.0.0.100 (12.0.0.100).

But on reception, when printing my server IP, it is 100.0.0.12 because of which, I am unable to track or validate the server details. I am not aware if it is due to little endian, big endian issues.

GDB prints on server IP: `{0xc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x64, 0x0 <repeats 12 times>}` But it actually has to be `{0x64, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc, 0x0 <repeats 12 times>}`

If it is due to little endian or big endian issues, can anyone tell me how to resolve the issue.

Please someone kindly help.

Comment: Network byte order is big-endian and x86 is little-endian. You need to use macro ntohl() and htonl() or ntohs() and htons() depending on the number of bytes you wish to swap.

Answer (score 1):

The wire format for IP addresses in the vast majority of protocols is big endian, whereas your appear to want the IP address in little endian format.

Macros `htonl` (host to network long) and `ntohl` (network to host long) are provided to convert the endianness from big endian, to whatever the host uses (big, little or mixed).

```
uint8_t  *packet;
uint32_t ip_net;
uint32_t ip_host;

memcpy(&ip_net, packet, sizeof(ip_net));  /* Assuming packet is a buffer of at least 4 bytes */
ip_host = ntohl(ip_net);
```

You may see instances in other code of pointers into packet buffers being cast to a uint32_t, and that being passed into the byte order conversion functions.  This may work on some architectures (x86), but can result in unaligned memory accesses on others (Sparc).

It's generally best practice to memcpy the from the buffer being processed to an intermediary variable, as memcpy will handle the alignment issues, and stack variables are guaranteed to be appropriately aligned.

There's a quick summary of these issues and the approaches available [here](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2490/ipro1-10/homeworks/homework_4b_alignment.html)

Comment: Solaris has conformed to the POSIX definition of `in_addr_t` as `uint32_t` since at least Solaris 10, and in practice has made it a 32-bit word for even longer,  If you need to copy from a buffer, one returned by `malloc()` will work (since that’s aligned for the type with the strictest requirements) or you can declare your buffer with `alignas`.

Comment: If the IP address is at the start of the buffer, yes.  If reading packets using libpcap or raw sockets, then you'll likely have the ethernet header in the buffer, which means the ip address fields may not be aligned even if the start of the buffer was.

Comment: If you give the copy operation the address of the buffer, it will copy to the start of the buffer.  In practical terms, if you know you’re going to store an IPv4 address, you’d make your buffer an `in_addr_t`,,or if you’re receiving some arbitrary kind of connection, such as listening for a connection over multiple network protocols, you’d allocate space for a `sockaddr_storage` and use the socket library to fill it.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to have libpcap or the raw socket API start the copy to your buffer from a specific offset in the incoming packet, so the libpcap > application buffer would need to be at least ``sizeof(l2 header) + sizeof(in_addr_t) || sizeof(sockaddr_storage)``.

Comment: You would have different buffers for the raw protocol header and the socket address, and your buffer for the data that comes over the net is probably a structure corresponding to the packet or header. If you need to represent multiple types in the buffer, it would be a `union`. At that point, you need to copy and reformat the data anyway. The standard does not guarantee that there will be no padding between the fields of the structure, so if you want completely portable code, you do need `memcpy()`. Natural alignment is enough for actually-existing CPUs, though.